# Enroll user's certificates for another user on the same machine

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, runas, client-certificate

If I'm logged in as a normal user, how can I download/enroll user's certificates for another user (on the same machine)? This can be done using runas command but can't figure out exactly.

Comment: Please check if this article was helpful to you: [Enroll for Certificates on Behalf of Other Users](https://forsenergy.com/en-us/certmgr/html/211b51a2-999a-43c0-86ac-92a32cbe1dd2.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition, I found the following option which can be done by normal users too.

1. In the PowerShell, use the following commands to run another user's PowerShell

   ```
   runas /user:<domain>\<username> powershell
   ```

   (this will prompt for the user's password)
2. On the user's PowerShell type ***certmgr*** and enrol the certificates for the user.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

- Start PowerShell as Administrator
- Do [`Enter-PSSession localhost -Credential (Get-Credential)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.1) and enter the credentials of the user that you want to add certificates on. (This may need a set up WinRM Service, use [`Enable-PSRemoting`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7.1) if you haven't have a running WinRM Service)
- Now you're in a PowerShell Session as the other user and can use [`Import-Certificate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-certificate?view=win10-ps) and [`Import-PfxCertificate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-pfxcertificate?view=win10-ps) etc. to add your Certificates for that user.

You can Check if it works by `cd`-ing and `gci`-ing around in the `Cert:` PSProvider after you imported the certs, they should be listed there. here's an example:

```
[localhost]: PS C:\Users\adminsystem\Documents> cd Cert:
[localhost]: PS Cert:\> cd CurrentUser
[localhost]: PS Cert:\CurrentUser> cd My
[localhost]: PS Cert:\CurrentUser\My> gci


   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\My

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
F0BD97B4EC6CD8B71C35631738259CF9F2E54381  CN=Adobe Content Certificate 10-5, OU=Cloud Technology, O=Adobe Systems, L=San Jose, S=California, C=US
D1DF7F06B769BCCB3F4479041EC1F06E9CD3CB1A  CN=Adobe Intermediate CA 10-3, OU=Cloud Technology, O=Adobe Systems, L=San Jose, S=California, C=US
```

or, instead of entering a PSSession (even though I feel this is very comfortable for this task), you can do it directly with [`Invoke-Command`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1) (from an elevated PowerShell)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost { Import-Certificate ... } -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

The third way - and the only way that works as a normal user is to simply start a new PowerShell as another user

```
start powershell -credential (Get-Credential)
```

and then do the cert import there.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful solution. But I need to perform this task without administrative privileges. I want my normal user to enrol another user without the need of admin privileges. So workaround on powershell runas commands would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Stackbe added a third way that you can try